# NLP: split dictionary and then transform it into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

My dataset looks like this

```
dt = [{author: ...., text: ....},...,{author: ...., text: ....}]
```

and I want to split the texts into chunks and then produce a dataframe with the following form:

```
df = chunk1 of text1    author of chunk1
     ...............    ................
```

etc

I can produce chunks by using this function

```
textwrap.wrap(text, width = 200, break_long_words=False)
```

and then transform it as a dataframe by using

```
# Convert the list of dictionaries to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dt)
```

but I don't know how to match each chunk with each author. I could be grateful if you could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use nested list comprehension to iterate through the rows in the original `dt` and then for each row, you iterate through the list of chunks split by `textwrap`, creating a new dictionary for each chunk with associated author. Does the code below give you the expected output?

```
import pandas as pd
import textwrap

# Sample data
dt = [{'author': 'A', 'text': 'Hello world!'}, {'author': 'B', 'text': '!dlrow olleH'}]

# Sample width
width=6

new_dt = [{'chunk': chunk, 'author': row['author']} for row in dt for chunk in textwrap.wrap(row['text'], width=width, break_long_words=False)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dt)
print(df)
```